# how i can filter the special character "ñ" in data set from delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have an application in delphi 7 that use a database query and bring information to client dataset. Then i need use the filter that provide the dataset to filter the info when the user press the keys. I have an issue with the character special "ñ" (aplication in spanish). The database connection is with PostgreSQL and works correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM public.users WHERE lastname ILIKE '%ñ%'
```

The function to filter the data is the following (simplified for this case):

```
procedure TfmForm.gdPersonalKeyPress(Sender: TObject;
  var Key: Char);
begin
  ClientDataSetUsers.Filtered := False;
  ClientDataSetUsers.Filter := ' UPPER(lastname) LIKE ' + #39 + '%' + UpperCase(lbSearch.Caption) + '%' + #39;
  ClientDataSetUsers.Filtered := True;
end;
```

This functionality also works well but not when I insert the character "Ñ" (it does not bring anything). Is there a way to filter the dataset using this character?

Comment: Imagine a world with Unicode

Comment: Do you know about the encoding of the string in your program vs on the database server ? Old Delphi versions are not using unicode, while the server might. `ñ` is `0xD1` in Western Ansi encoding, but `C3 91` in UTF8. Also `UpperCase` may not affect accented characters ? Just assumption, did not have a chance to test.  @DavidHeffernan  you are correct, but there can be many reasons why people stay with the old. D7 is a simple to use, simple to learn, compiles fast, and will not expire every year.

Comment: No Delphi Version expires after a year!  Though I do agree Delphi 7 is the best!

Comment: MyICQ. The truth is that I had seen it but until now no problems of this type had arisen. On the side of the uppercase that you mention, it can be a problem, since it is done like this so that the uppercase character matches between what is inserted by the keyboard and its comparison, but in the case of the "ñ" for more than being in an "UpperCase It remains in lowercase. I am going to investigate what solution can be given using unicode

Comment: @TobyAllen wrong, the Community Edition does! But you can renew the license for another year for free at least.

Comment: @Toby Delphi 7 is definitely not the best version. Inability to code efficiently for international audiences is too great a handicap.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan! :)

Answer (score -1):

`AnsiUpperCase('ñ')`
was the answer that solved the problem

Comment: You should always [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) your user's input - in this case lowercase it always. Why not using the `ILIKE` operator in the filter, too?

Comment: "ILIKE" in the dataset filter has not worked for me